# Remove UIView From UIWindow

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uikit

I have a `UIViewController` whose view is added to my `UIWindow`. However, if I remove the view, I cannot tap anything below where it was. My code is below:

```
-(void)createFullAd{
    UIViewController *viewController = [UIViewController new];
    self.fullAd = [MobclixFullScreenAdViewController new];
    self.fullAd.delegate = self;
    [self.fullAd requestAndDisplayAdFromViewController:viewController];
    viewController.view.tag = 999999;
    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]window] addSubview:viewController.view];
}

- (void)fullScreenAdViewControllerDidDismissAd:(MobclixFullScreenAdViewController*)fullScreenAdViewController{
    NSLog(@"Dismissed");
    [[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] viewWithTag:999999]removeFromSuperview];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@dasblinkenlight gave me the idea for this, if he posts back I will award the answer to him.

This is messy but it is the only thing that has worked:

```
-(void)displayAd {
    self.fullAd = [MobclixFullScreenAdViewController new];
    self.fullAd.delegate = self;
    self.adController = [UIViewController new];
    [self.fullAd requestAndDisplayAdFromViewController:self.adController];
    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]window] addSubview:self.adController.view];
}
- (void)fullScreenAdViewControllerDidDismissAd:(MobclixFullScreenAdViewController*)fullScreenAdViewController{
    [fullScreenAdViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]window] setNeedsLayout];
    self.adController = nil;

}
```

`setNeedsLayout` is the key, but I called it on the window instead of the adController's superview.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just not the correct view hierarchy. If your building target is iOS 5.0+, I think you should consider using `[viewController1 addChildViewController:viewController2]`

Answer (score 0):

May try this :

```
-(void)fullScreenAdViewControllerDidDismissAd(MobclixFullScreenAdViewController*)fullScreenAdViewController
{
    NSLog(@"Dismissed");
    [fullScreenAdViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```